# Displaying live scorecard on linux desktop

Tags: python, xml, linux, elementtree

I have written a python script which displays all the live matches scores. I wish to display the score on my desktop rather than in terminal. I also wish to update the score card every 5 minutes or so.
Here is the python script:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import requests
tree = ET.fromstring(requests.get('http://www.cricbuzz.com/livecricketscore/home-score-matches.xml').text)
for elem in tree.iter('match'):
    state = elem.find('state').text
    footer = elem.find('footer').text
    header = elem.find('header').text
    print state,header,footer
```

[xml file used for parsing](http://www.cricbuzz.com/livecricketscore/home-score-matches.xml)

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a GUI for this. There are a lot of libraries that should help. A couple as example - [PyQT4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt4), [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any fancy GUI stuff like Vikas Neha Suggested. All you need is pynotify library.

```
pynotify.init("TEST")
notice=pynotify.Notification("Your Score card",string_to_show)
notice.show()
```

This would Display your message onto the Bubble notification on your screen.